# HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException: The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST in Laravel

Tags: php, api, error-handling, laravel-8

I have used REST API & Web in same laravel project. Both working in localhost. But not in server.

I have used Postman for the REST API checking. I'm sharing my route code below,

This my `api.php` code.

```
// Customer registration
Route::post('signup/', "api\CustomerAccountController@customerRegistration");
```

REST API testing from the server. Go to the link below.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/13N71hqWQFXZcKNzSjr1eqqe7DUhPnnr6/view?usp=sharing

```
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException: The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST. in file /home1/foresqtn/quizapi.biconconsultants.com/quizapi/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/AbstractRouteCollection.php on line 117
```

This code is uploaded to the server.
Now I am sharing the localhost response with same code. Go to the below link.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gK1cO7tmvG3f6EsYqQS-1n3OpXCrVskr/view?usp=sharing

Now I couldn't find what I'm doing wrong here. I am running same code.

Your valuable response will be appreciated.

Comment: Please include relevant information as text, not images. It is easier to read, it can be copied and you could much easier redact any personal bits of information you wish to hide. Plus, images can be lost after some time and then your question will lose its context.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem Solved**

In Postman when I'm trying to send a request using the endpoint, in the end of the URL I'm adding '/' that's why I was getting the above Error. Now the error is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

If you just use "http" instead of "https" your problem will be solved. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you're route in the auth middleware group, just try to add Bearer token, everything will work